# How to create a javascript slider with divs instead of images

Tags: javascript, html, slider

So as the title suggests i need my slider to slide divs instead of images, how can i do that? I tried googling but all i could find was a bunch of jQuery tutorials.

This is my html

```
<div id="slider">
<img src="1.jpg" name="slide">
<input type="button" value="previous" onClick="prev();">
<input type="button" value="next" onClick="next();">
</div>
```

And Javascript

```
var show = new Array(3);
show[0] = new Image;
show[0].src = "0.jpg";
show[1] = new Image;
show[1].src = "1.jpg";
show[2] = new Image;
show[2].src = "2.jpg";
show[3] = new Image;
show[3].src = "3.jpg";
var n=0;
 function next(){
    n++;
    if(n > 2){
        n=0;
    }
    document.slide.src = show[n].src;
 }
 function prev(){
    n--;
    if(n < 0){
        n=2;
    }
    document.slide.src = show[n].src;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bxSlider: jQuery Content Slider | Responsive jQuery Slider](http://bxslider.com/)

Comment: I'm looking for a simple javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

I would think your solution would involve radio buttons and display: none for all divs other than the one that is currently selected. A CSS animation should be able to help you give a slideshow effect. I can't find any answer on doing this with straight JavaScript using slide